# What to import in AS3 to allow "addEventListener"?

Tags: actionscript-3, import, addeventlistener

This is an extremely basic question (I'm sort of new to AS3) but what do you import in AS3 to allow "addEventListener"? I made the mistake of learning how to program in the timeline and now this jump over is kind of tricky.

EDIT: Here is my code (there are countless errors, but I just want to fix the addEventListener ones):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;

public class TheGameItself extends MovieClip
{

    public static function startit(stage)
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movecat);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spawnanimal);
        var myDelay:Timer = new Timer(100);
        myDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showMessage);
        myDelay.start();
        var myMouse = 0;
        var speed = 1;
        var wave = 1;
        var score = 0;
        var rnum = 0;
        var moveornot = false;
    }
    function showMessage(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        moveornot = true;
    }

    function movecat(event)
    {
        if ((mouseY > 40) && (mouseY < 330))
        {
            cat.y = mouseY;
        }
    }
    function spawnanimal(event)
    {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((100 / wave) - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        if (rnum == 5)
        {
            myMouse = new mouse();
            myMouse.x = 0;
            myMouse.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (350 - 45 + 1)) + 45;
            addChild(myMouse);
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                if (moveornot == true)
                {
                    myMouse[i].y +=  speed * 100;
                    moveornot == false;
                    if ((myMouse.x == 500) || (myMouse.hitTestObject(cat)))
                    {
                        myMouse.visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a class that can dispatch events, then extend `flash.events.EventDispatcher`. That will provide the `addEventListener` and `dispatchEvent` methods on objects that are instances of that class. For objects that listen to the events, you don't need to import anything.

in `com/foo/MyClass.as`:

```
package com.foo {
   import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

   public class MyClass extends EventDispatcher
   {

   }

   public function doSomething():void
   {
       dispatchEvent( new Event("eventType"));
   } 
}
```

elsewhere:

```
import com.foo.MyClass;

var obj:MyClass = new MyClass();
obj.addEventListener("eventType", onEvent);

obj.doSomething();

function onEvent(event:Event):void
{
    trace("the event happened");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not access an instance of an object through a static function.
in the following code:

```
public static function startit(stage)
{
  addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movecat);
  addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spawnanimal);
  var myDelay:Timer = new Timer(100);
}
```

by doing:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movecat);
```

you are essentially doing:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movecat);
```

which is saying add the listener to the current instantiation, but you declared the function as static, which won't allow you to do it.

Do away with the static reference to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
```

See [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29).

For eg., if you extend `EventDispatcher` like this:

```
public class MyClass extends EventDispatcher {
...
}
```

Then you can use `addEventListener()` on any instance of `MyClass` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the API of the event about to use. If you are going to use an `EnterFrame` event then you should import `flash.Events.Event`. Because `EnterFrame` event coded in the `Event` API. For more details visit [ADOBE Documentation about Events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/package-detail.html).

If you want to initialize once it is added to stage, you can avail this

```
 this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
```

Also in you code you were declared some variables inside the static function. You will get error when you tried to access these variables outside that function. If you want to have it common for all functions then declare it as global variable.

I am not sure why you used static function. If possible, try to avail the above said listener to avoid a static function call in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As `TheGameItself` extends `MovieClip`, you don't need to include anything - `MovieClip` already extends `EventDispatcher`. Your problem here is that `startit()` is a static function, while `addEventListener()` is an object function.

Remove the static from `startIt()`, create your instance of `TheGameItself`, and it should be fine.

E.g. (in your main class):

```
var game:TheGameItself = new TheGameItself; // hold a reference to this somewhere, otherwise it'll be gc'd
game.startIt();
```

On a somewhat related note, `myMouse`, `score` etc will all be local variables to the `startIt()` function, so they won't exist when the function exits